# Ordered picking value from 2nd column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a parameter as AD in columns. But it is different sequence in per row. How can i pick 'AD' from X2.

```
X1                      X2
GT:GQ:GQX:DPI:AD:DP     0/1:909:12:125:93,26:119
GT:GQ:GQX:DPI:AD        0/1:909:12:125:35,24
GT:GQ:GQX:DP:DPF:AD     0/1:57:3:11:130:8,3
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL          0/1:211,31:242:99:138,0,7251
```

Output

```
AD
93,26
35,24
8,3
211,31
```

Comment: Please provide your data in reproducible format next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split columns at `":"` using `strsplit` and select `"AD"` position identified using `grep` with an `mapply`.

```
mapply(`[`, strsplit(d$X2, ":"), sapply(strsplit(d$X1,":"), grep, pattern="AD"))
# [1] "93,26"  "35,24"  "8,3"    "211,31"
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(X1 = c("GT:GQ:GQX:DPI:AD:DP", "GT:GQ:GQX:DPI:AD", 
"GT:GQ:GQX:DP:DPF:AD", "GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL"), X2 = c("0/1:909:12:125:93,26:119", 
"0/1:909:12:125:35,24", "0/1:57:3:11:130:8,3", "0/1:211,31:242:99:138,0,7251"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: if "PL" is also a value as 23,26. And if it comes before "AD" ?

Comment: @ersan Seems I misunderstood question a little, check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Using base `R` and split to extract the "AD" element.

```
mapply(
  function(x,  i) x[i],
  strsplit(df$X2, ":"),
  lapply(strsplit(df$X1, ":"), function(x) which(x == "AD"))
)
[1] "93,26"  "35,24"  "8,3"    "211,31"
```

Reproducible data

```
df <- data.frame(
  X1 = c("GT:GQ:GQX:DPI:AD:DP", "GT:GQ:GQX:DPI:AD", "GT:GQ:GQX:DP:DPF:AD", "GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL"), 
  X2 = c("0/1:909:12:125:93,26:119", "0/1:909:12:125:35,24", "0/1:57:3:11:130:8,3", "0/1:211,31:242:99:138,0,7251")
)
```

Comment: if "PL" is also a value as 23,26. And if it comes before "AD"

Comment: @ersan So I guess I have misunderstood, you need both columns to extract the correct input? Please see updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `regmatches` + `regexpr` when with base R

```
> unlist(regmatches(df$X2,regexpr("\\d+,\\d+",df$X2)))
[1] "93,26"  "35,24"  "8,3"    "211,31"
```

Comment: if "PL" is also a value as 23,26. And if it comes before "AD"